# How to add mandatory where clause in SObjectSelector subclasses

Tags: apex, fflib

I have a Product selector class and would like to enforce a mandatory check on a Product field for every query on products. I'm assuming it has something to do with the QueryFactory, but since there is no reference to a QueryFactory being maintained in the SObjectSelector class, I can't figure out how to add this condition to every QueryFactory instance of my Productselector class.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

Given a Product2 selector class something like the following:

```
public virtual class ProductsSelector  implements IProductsSelector {

    public override String getOrderby() {return 'ProductCode';}

    public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
        return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {  
                Product2.ID,
                Product2.Description,
                ...  
        };
    }

    public static IProductsSelector newInstance()    {
        return (IProductsSelector) 
           Application.Selector.newInstance(Product2.SObjectType);
    }

    public Schema.SobjectType getSObjectType() {return Product2.SObjectType;}

    public virtual List<Product2> selectById(Set<ID> ids){
        return (List<Product2>) selectSObjectsById(ids);
    }

    public virtual List<Product2> selectByProductCode(set<String> productCodes) {
        fflib_QueryFactory pQueryFactory    = newQueryFactory()                                                      
             .setCondition('ProductCode IN :productCodes ' + getMandatoryCondition())
                                                ;
        return Database.query(pQueryFactory.toSOQL());
    } 

    public virtual List<Product2> selectByName(set<String> productNames) {
       fflib_QueryFactory pQueryFactory = newQueryFactory()                                                      
                 .setCondition('ProductCode IN :productCodes ' + getMandatoryCondition() )
                                                    ;
      return Database.query(pQueryFactory.toSOQL());
    } 

   private String getMandatoryCondition() {
     return ' AND MyMandatory_Field__c != null ';
   }
}
```

you can add a mandatory condition into each of your setCondition calls